# Mvc 4 script bundles and GZip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, gzip, bundle

I've add all scripts from my site into very big bundle (about 700kb). And now I want IIS to gzip it, but i can't.

I've tried everything I've found here and over the web, but nothing helps. Static *.js files age gzipped, but complete bundle not.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Check the [dynamic compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730629%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in IIS. It have to be enabled for both IIS and your website. You also must have a valid config in the applicationHost.config too.

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

**Important Note :** the content type of Bundling response  is `text/javascript`, so check your config for this type.

Comment: As some other people say, try not to use notepad++ or notepad but appcmd.exe to edit the applicationHost file this single command helped me to edit the file: appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/javascript', enabled='True']" /commit:apphost